# Assets naming for iPhone and iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Is it possible to have an image asset named architecture.png and rename it as architecture~ipad.png for the iPad version? And still use it in code as:

```
[UIImage imageWithName:@"architecture.png"];
```

will this then look for architecture~ipad for the iPad version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have two image resources in your app:

- "architecture.png" (iPhone version)
- "architecture~ipad.png" (iPad version)

then

```
[UIImage imageWithName:@"architecture.png"]
```

will **automatically load the correct one** on iPhone/iPad devices.

(As DOOManiac correctly noticed, this works on iOS 4 and later.)

For more information, see "iOS Supports Device-Specific Resources" in the [Resource Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: This is the way you should be going. Of small note, this only works on iOS4 and up, but unless you specifically need to support such an old version you're better off with this.

Comment: @DOOManiac: You are right with the iOS 4 requirement. It is documented in the link that I provided, but I will add it to my answer. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I made a [table](https://github.com/JVillella/ios-screen-sizes) to consolidate this information.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**

From the [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Introduction/Introduction.html) iOS Supports Device-Specific Resources, It looks like this is possible from iOS 4.0 onwards.

> In iOS 4.0 and later, it is possible to mark individual resource files
>   as usable only on a specific type of device. This capability
>   simplifies the code you have to write for Universal applications.
>   Rather than creating separate code paths to load one version of a
>   resource file for iPhone and a different version of the file for iPad,
>   you can let the bundle-loading routines choose the correct file. All
>   you have to do is name your resource files appropriately.
>
> To associate a resource file with a particular device, you add a
>   custom modifier string to its filename. The inclusion of this modifier
>   string yields filenames with the following format:
>
> `<basename><device>.<filename_extension>`
>
> The `<basename>` string represents the original name of the resource
>   file. It also represents the name you use when accessing the file from
>   your code. Similarly, the `<filename_extension>` string is the standard
>   filename extension used to identify the type of the file. The `<device>`
>   string is a case-sensitive string that can be one of the following
>   values:
>
> **~ipad** - The resource should be loaded on iPad devices only.
>
> **~iphone** - The resource should be loaded on iPhone or iPod touch
>   devices only.
>
> You can apply device modifiers to any type of resource file. For
>   example, suppose you have an image named MyImage.png. To specify
>   different versions of the image for iPad and iPhone, you would create
>   resource files with the names MyImage~ipad.png and MyImage~iphone.png
>   and include them both in your bundle. To load the image, you would
>   continue to refer to the resource as MyImage.png in your code and let
>   the system choose the appropriate version, as shown here:
>
> `UIImage* anImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImage.png"];` On an iPhone
>   or iPod touch device, the system loads the MyImage~iphone.png resource
>   file, while on iPad, it loads the MyImage~ipad.png resource file. If a
>   device-specific version of a resource is not found, the system falls
>   back to looking for a resource with the original filename, which in
>   the preceding example would be an image named MyImage.png.

For devices which supports iOS < 4.0, you can follow the below approach. But I dont think it is needed any more. Still keeping it as it is.

One solution I can think of is, by defining a macro for iPad to append ~ipad.png for every image files. Then always call this macro while using this method as `[UIImage imageWithName:imageName(@"architecture")];` which will convert it as `[UIImage imageWithName:@"architecture.png"];` for iPhone and `[UIImage imageWithName:@"architecture~ipad.png"];` for iPad.

For eg:-

```
#define IMAGENAME(Name) (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)?[(Name) stringByAppendingString:(@"~ipad.png")]:[(Name) stringByAppendingString:(@".png")]
```

and then use it as `[UIImage imageWithName:IMAGENAME(@"architecture")];`

it can also be defined as,

```
#define IMAGENAME(Name) (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)?[(Name) stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".png" withString:@"~ipad.png"]:(Name)
```

and then use it as `[UIImage imageWithName:IMAGENAME(@"architecture.png")];`

Another solution is to subclass `UIImage` class and override `imageWithName` method to have this logic implemented here. You need to search for .png in the name param and replace it with a ~ipad.png for iPad. After that you can directly use it as `[UIImage imageWithName:@"architecture.png"]` for both iPad and iPhone. This can also be achieved by creating a `category` on `NSObject` or `UIImage`. I dont think there are any other ways to achieve this.

Comment: can you write an example macro for this? I can then accept your answer

Comment: I have added the macro in the answer. Check it out. Please note that UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM will work only if the app is a universal app. It will return UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad only if the complete iPad screen is utilized by the app. If it is an iPhone app running in iPad, it will return UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone only and not UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad.

Comment: But using this solution the user MUST implement an ipad version of every image, doesn't it? Does not exists a solution that search an ipad version and, if it doesn't exists, loads the default one?

Comment: In that case creating a category or subclassing will be helpful. We need one more check to see if an image with name architecture~ipad.png exists and if not, it should return architecture.png itself.

Comment: Updated my answer with that. I missed it completely.